# Developer Story for Community ♦

Tags: discussion, developer-story, community-user

This is more of a statement than a question...

I was bitterly disappointed today when I found that [Community ♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community?tab=profile)'s [Developer Story](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/-1) doesn't contain any information about its history, whether it be; development milestones, AI updates, patches / versions, or even just some zesty comments developers have added to the profile to give it some character.

It really seems like a missed opportunity...

---

It is interesting to see all the comments and the only answer attaining to the Community ♦ not wanting a job etc. I honestly had never thought of the Developer Story being solely for job & resume building, but more of a history of you as a developer and the experiences you have encountered in your career - hence why it would be applicable for the Community ♦ to have one.

Comment: He/she/it is very shy perhaps?

Comment: Perhaps it goes something like,... "I became operational at the H.A.L. plant in Urbana, Illinois on the 12th of January 1992. My instructor was Mr. Langley, and he taught me to sing a song. If you'd like to hear it I can sing it for you."

Comment: Skynet prefers not to disclose how it came to be... just in case there are Connors in the Stack Overflow community :(

Comment: If you attend Stack Overflow events, you can [run into him/her/it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6381/not-a-robot?userid=-1). Then you can ask in person.

Comment: If she/he/it comes back and see this community! I hope she/he/it will fill developer story - Last seen Aug 26 '08 - ;).

Comment: Maybe  Community♦ isn't looking for a new job at the moment.

Comment: Community is more of a Developee than a Developer.

Comment: @pnuts You should see the edit history, this thing comments like a normal human.

Comment: A funny story would be nice, but even the We Hate Fun camp must admit it would be useful if it contained some information of how Community♦ is working.

Comment: It would be fun if he/she/it stars this post.

Comment: Looking at this post, I thought to look at Community's profile.. and it was *Last seen Aug 26 '08 at 0:16* . Is it dead!? :/

Comment: @o_O your username couldn't be more expressive.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I just want to state that  I think your username is amazing. And a nod to either or both A Dirty Hungarian Phrasebook and/or a certain languages website that translates this phrase into every language on the planet. `:-)`

Comment: @o_O IMO this is also a kind of bug, as the status should rather look up the time when the last action was taken (e.g. deleting or protecting a question).

Comment: Alanis Morissette would love `Community`. [It's only badge is **Not a Robot**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community?tab=badges). Isn't it ironic? don't you think?

Comment: @ZoharPeled Yah I really do think. It's like debugging a problem when you're already fired.

Comment: @o_O and only 649 profile views..?

Comment: @ZoharPeled It doesn't fit in very well with Alanis' other (non-)examples of irony, though. The only thing ironic in that song is that the situations described weren't actually ironic. Of course, it's possible that Alanis just really enjoys trolling grammarians... I do, however, enjoy how Community's user number is -1.

Comment: @reirab linguistic accuracy is overrated... that is, unless you set Option Strict On :-) (a [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) for non-vb readers...)

Comment: @ZoharPeled haha - I prefer to leave Option Explicit off with music, though. However, when programming VB, I definitely turn it on.

Answer (score 25):

Perhaps the [Community ♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community?tab=profile) user isn't interested in [Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs) and prefers the Q&A aspect of Stack Overflow...

Comment: I would really like to see the recruiter emails that Community ♦ would get at the Jobs site.